# FIND_IN_SET in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hey, I just want to know if it's ok to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE FIND_IN_SET("value1", `field1`)
```

as opposed to this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE FIND_IN_SET("value1", `field1`) > 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. If it finds the value, then the result will be greater than 0, which MySQL will interpret as TRUE.